# Python-Write Data to hdf5 File

Tags: python, hdf5

I want to write complex-data into a (6,31) dimensional dataset.
In the first column there should be the first complex-data from the first input-textfile, in the secound there should be the data form the secound input-textilfe...

```
import numpy,sys
import h5py as H5


#######################################################

def CreateH5(argv):
    F=H5.File("S12.h5","w")
    dset=F.create_dataset('S11',(6,31),dtype='complex128')

    for arg in argv:
            S11f = numpy.loadtxt(arg,skiprows=3)
            S11fc=S11f[:,1]*numpy.exp(S11f[:,-1]*1j*(180./numpy.pi))

            for i in range(dset):
                    dset[i]=S11fc


if __name__=='__main__':
    CreateH5(sys.argv[1:])
```

I dont know how to handle the `for i in range(dset):`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you are trying to do with your forloop. What I understand is that you have 6 files with 31 complex values in each one and you want that values in your dataset?

If so, simply enumerate your loop on argv and put numpy array into the dataset:

```
for index, arg in enumerate(argv):
    S11f = numpy.loadtxt(arg,skiprows=3)
    S11fc=S11f[:,1]*numpy.exp(S11f[:,-1]*1j*(180./numpy.pi))
    dset[index] = S11fc
```

But why use an hd5f instead of a simple numpy array?